# Apache Spark: Unexpected filter results

Tags: apache-spark, filter, rdd

I am working with Apache Spark v 1.2 in local mode. I have created an RDD and persisted it in memory. The Spark Web UI shows that 85% of this RDD is stored in memory. I have a feature/variable in the RDD that has values of 0,1 as demonstrated by the result I get by running the script below:

```
In[96]: flagged.map(lambda x:(x[14],1)).reduceByKey(lambda x,y:x+y).collect()

Out[96]: [(0, 637981), (1, 272958)]
```

Also when I do a flagged.count() the number is the sum of the two values  i.e. 637981+272958 = 910939

Now when I run a filter based on this, I do not get the same counts:

```
In[97]:  flagged.filter(lambda x: x[14]==0).count()

Out[97]:  637344

In[97]:  flagged.filter(lambda x: x[14]==1).count()

Out[97]:  272988
```

I am struggling to understand that why do the numbers produced from the filtered RDDs do not match that of the reduceByKey method.

Answer (score 0):

Use cache type `MEMORY_AND_DISK`

```
rdd.persist(org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
```

For a moment I felt it is a bug, I executed a sample job and it looked like you are right

```
  val count3 = sc.parallelize(1 to 1000000).map(r => {
    (new java.util.Random().nextInt(2), 1)
  })


 count3.reduceByKey(_+_).collect
```

res10: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((0,500201), (1,499799))

```
 count3.filter(r => r._1==0).count
```

res13: Long = 499613

```
 count3.filter(r => r._1==1).count
```

res14: Long = 500143

But then I changed my code to

```
 val count3 = sc.parallelize(1 to 1000000).map(r => {
    (new java.util.Random().nextInt(2), 1)
  }).persist()
count3.count
```

Please note that I added persist this time (and I was able to cache 100% of this rdd)

```
count3.reduceByKey(_+_).collect
```

res27: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((0,500048), (1,499952))

```
 count3.filter(r => r._1==0).count
```

res28: Long = 500048

```
 count3.filter(r => r._1==1).count
```

res29: Long = 499952

I think you are generating RDD and then persisting it, default cache type is `MEMORY_ONLY`. Now the problem is that you are able to cache only 85% of rdd in memory which means remaining 15% will be recomputed on demand. If you are using some random function while creating rdd this 15% data can change during recomputation.

Comment: @FawadAlam Please upvote and select this answer then. Thanks.